# All iOS provisioning profiles stuck at pending

Tags: macos, xcode, ios, development

I'm attempting to create new iOS provisioning profiles, but as I create them the Apple website hangs as I submit the 'Name the profile and generate' page.

Returning to the list of profiles I can see the new profile but it remains at 'Pending' and does not allow me to use it.

I'm using Xcode 5 and hitting refresh on the Accounts preference pane does not delete the old profiles, or make any change to the pending profiles online.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem as yours, but I have an OSX provisioning profile that is managed by xcode that is also stuck in the pending state.

To workaround the problem:

- I downloaded an older manually created profile from the web interface.
- Opened Xcode 4 and dragged the profile into the organiser.
- Closed Xcode 4
- Opened Xcode 5 and was able to select this profile and build again.

A spotlight search didn't show the profile existing anywhere new so I'm not sure what Xcode 4 is actually doing that Xcode 5 can pick up.